# Parse a number with dot as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator

Tags: php, numbers, decimal

I am working with CSV files and Excel often format prices like this:

```
$ 384.642,54
```

Where the Decimal is 54. I need to round this number to `384.643` (always round up).

What I've done is first: Remove spaces and the $ sign that excel puts in the cell.
What I have now is this number `384.642,54`. I need PHP to know the decimal is the Coma and the dot is the thousand separator, then round it.

I haven't been able to achieve this with number_format. It returns me `384`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
$number = str_replace('.', '', $number);
$number = str_replace(',', '.', $number);
$number = ceil($number);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comment, the least invasive way is to str_replace() the unwanted parts. And then use `ceil()` to round-up.

```
$num = '$ 384.642,54';
//- replace not wanted characters with ''
    $num = str_replace(array('$',' ','.'), '');

//- convert the comma to decimal point, and transform it to a float
    $num = floatval(str_replace(',','.'));

echo ceil($num);
```

Optionally you can use preg_replace() to 'smart' replace things, but for this setup it's not cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest and the least involved solution: use `str_replace` to replace dots with empty string; then use it again to replace comma with dot; then use `floatval` to convert string to number and then round it any way you want:

```
$result = round(floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', '384.642,54'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = '$ 384.642,54';
echo number_format(
  ceil(
    str_replace(
     array('.', '$', ' ', ','), 
     array('', '', '', '.'), 
     $num
    )
  ), 0, '', '.'
);
```